# SSL certificate connection to the database in Spring Data JPA

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, ssl, spring-data-jpa

I have a database protected by certificates, I managed to connect to it through the IDEA interface.
[image]

[image]

what I need to write in application.yml to connect to db in Spring data jpa ?

I tried to connect in the usual way but it didn't work
[image]

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:693) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:199) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1158) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
at com.example.dbconnection.DbConnectionApplication.main(DbConnectionApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Suppressed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.192.187", user "integration_api", database "integration_db", SSL off
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:693) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:267) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

I try this config

[image]

But now I get this error,

```
Could not open SSL root certificate file 'db-cert.pem'.
at org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory.<init>(LibPQFactory.java:150) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
at org.postgresql.core.SocketFactoryFactory.getSslSocketFactory(SocketFactoryFactory.java:61) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:34) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]



Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 'db-cert.pem' (The specified file cannot be found)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111) ~[na:na]
at org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory.<init>(LibPQFactory.java:147) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
... 55 common frames omitted
```

path to file

[image]

Comment: Is your client certificate registered for your user at the database? Does the client key match the client certificate? Is the server certificate signed with the CA certificate?

Comment: I am not sure that I will answer these questions correctly since the logins and certificates were given to me, but as far as I know.
the client certificate is registered for the user in the database.
the client key corresponds to the client certificate, since I managed to connect through the IDE.
as far as I know, the servers are not signed with a certificate authority certificate.

Comment: I would like to find out how spring boot usually connects to the database using certificates.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I thought it was about getting it to work in IntelliJ. Does [Spring Boot connection to Postgresql with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54257758) help? If not, please show what you tried to get it work with Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now I have a problem with the fact that I can't get the path to the certificate file. I have updated the body of the question, there is more about the new problem

Comment: What about putting them right next to the application instead of using the resource folder? Alternatively, you _could_ try `classpath:` URLs.

Comment: I tried, the same result. Maybe I made a mistake somehow,  I wrote it like this classpath:client-cert.pem